# How to define an optional argument to Route callback

Tags: 8, routes

I want define a simple controller action, which receive optional argument:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello\Controller;

class SimpleCallback extends ControllerBase
{
    public function sayHiAction($name = 'there')
    {
        return new Response('Hi ' . $name, 200);
    }
}
?>
```

If I define the routing like this

```
# file @hello.routing.yml
hello.sayHi:
  path: '/hello/{name}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
  requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

GET `/hello` just gives me 404 response.

Follow [official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643), I updated my route:

```
# file @hello.routing.yml
hello.sayHi:
  path: '/hello/{name}'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
    custom_arg: 'there'
  requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

But nothing changed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The docs you link to say:

> Finally, if any static arguments should be passed to the controller, provide those in the defaults array as well. **Name them to match the arguments of your controller method**. See below.

Emphasis mine.

So your code should be:

```
# file @hello.routing.yml
hello.sayHi:
  path: '/hello/{name}'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Say Hi'
    _content: 'Drupal\hello\Controller\SimpleCallback::sayHiAction'
    name: 'there'
  requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

See also [Required and Optional Placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders) in the Symfony routing docs.

Comment: "Name them to match the arguments of your controller method". Yeah there's some magic that won't work if you name it differently.